# JQuery - Get values from html array inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

A user has the capacity to add as many items as possible through html inputs. The inputs look like;

```
 <input class="form-control" name="part_number[]" number" type="text">
 <input class="form-control" name="part_number[]" number" type="text">
 <input class="form-control" name="part_number[]" number" type="text">

 <input class="form-control item" name="description[]" type="text">
 <input class="form-control item" name="description[]" type="text">
 <input class="form-control item" name="description[]" type="text">
```

I would like to add the items to my database for storage.. How do i iternate through each input? part number and description belong to a single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I understand that you want the description and part number in a row.
Please find my answer using [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function of jQuery. 
 
The `.each()` function iterates through all the specified elements and it returns the index position of each element. Here I'm iterating through the part number, so I want to take the corresponding description, that is the description at the index position of part_number. To achieve this am using another jQuery selector [:eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/). It will select the element at index n within the matched set.

```js
$(".submit").on("click", function(){
let user_input = [];
$("input[name='part_number[]']").each(function(index){
 user_input.push({
 part_number: $(this).val(),
 description: $(`.item:eq(${index})`).val()
 });
});
console.log("final result = ", user_input);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" name="part_number[]"  placeholder="number" type="text">
 <input class="form-control" name="part_number[]" placeholder="number" type="text">
 <input class="form-control" name="part_number[]" placeholder="number" type="text">

 <input class="form-control item" name="description[]" placeholder="description" type="text">
 <input class="form-control item" name="description[]" placeholder="description" type="text">
 <input class="form-control item" name="description[]" placeholder="description" type="text">
 
 <button type="submit" class="submit"> Save</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function getdata() {
  var partNumbers = [];
  var descriptions = [];
  $('[name="part_number[]"]').each(function() {
    partNumbers.push(this.value);
  })
  $('[name="description[]"]').each(function() {
    descriptions.push(this.value);
  })
  var data = {
    partNumbers: partNumbers,
    descriptions: descriptions
  }
  $('#output').val(JSON.stringify(data))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" name="part_number[]" type="text" value="part number 1">
<input class="form-control" name="part_number[]" type="text" value="part number 2">
<input class="form-control" name="part_number[]" type="text" value="part number 3">
<br>
<input class="form-control item" name="description[]" type="text" value="description 1">
<input class="form-control item" name="description[]" type="text" value="description 2">
<input class="form-control item" name="description[]" type="text" value="description 3">
<hr>
<button type="button" onclick="getdata()">get data</button>
<textarea id="output" rows="10" cols="100" placeholder="output"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your inputs are within a form, you can use `.serializeArray()` and then `.reduce()` it to create an object which stores keys and array values for multiple input types like below. You can then submit this data to your server to then store in your database:

```js
const data = $("#myform").serializeArray().reduce((acc, o) => {
  if (o.name.slice(-2) === "[]") {
    acc[o.name] = acc[o.name] || [];
    acc[o.name].push(o.value);
  } else {
    acc[o.name] = o.value;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(data); // data to POST
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform">
  <input class="form-control" name="part_number[]" value="pn1" type="text">
  <input class="form-control" name="part_number[]" value="pn2" type="text">
  <input class="form-control" name="part_number[]" value="pn3" type="text">

  <input class="form-control item" name="description[]" value="desc1" type="text">
  <input class="form-control item" name="description[]" value="desc2" type="text">
  <input class="form-control item" name="description[]" value="desc3" type="text">

  <input class="form-control item" name="single_data" value="non-array data" type="text">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather fix the HTML than trying to fix the data afterwards.

You have `items` with the values `description`and `part_number`, in order to group the data i would firstly group them visually in your HTML by adding a wrapper around each `part_number` + `description`  pair:

```
<div class="item">
    <input type="text" name="part_number[]" />
    <input type="text" name="decription[]" />
</div>
```

After that we fix the input names' and add them to a group `item`:

```
<div class="item">
    <input type="text" name="item[part_number]" />
    <input type="text" name="item[decription]" />
</div>
```

To add multiple item elements in your form you need to add an ID to each item when adding it to your form:

```
<div class="item">
    <input type="text" name="item[0][part_number]" />
    <input type="text" name="item[0][decription]" />
</div>
<div class="item">
    <input type="text" name="item[1][part_number]" />
    <input type="text" name="item[1][decription]" />
</div>
```

When adding these values to your database you can then iterate over them like so: ( I'm just guessing you will use PHP)

```
foreach( $_POST['item'] as $item) {
    $item['part_number'];
    $item['description];
}
```