# JavaScript turn a form's multiple checkboxes into an object

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript method that I believe is breaking when the form has multiple checkbox values selected:

```
function formToObject(formData) {
     var p = {};
     $.each($(formData).serializeArray(),function(i, e){
        p[e.name] = e.value;
     });

     console.log(p);
     return p;
}
```

The paramater `formData` is the `(#formID)` of any given form that I am working with.

If I am correct, how would I modify this to allow multiple checkboxes to be sent into `$_POST`?

Comment: Start by giving an explanation why you are not using `.serialize()` to begin with. What is `formData`?

Comment: post edited to answer the parameter question

Comment: If you have a list of input parameters using `name="xxx[]"`, jquery's serializeArray won't group those into an array. Maybe you're after something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57358347/5648954

Comment: So why are you not using `.serialize()` then?

Comment: `.serialize()` turns into a string - i need object `key => values` for my app

Comment: @ZachSmith you mentioned that you want to send your checkboxes via POST, if that's the case, you can POST the string returned by `.serialize()` (it doesn't need to be in the form of an object)

Comment: @NickParsons yes i understand that. but why do extra logic via my app, when i can handle all of this with js? the solution you link to your previous comment works prefectly.